MS Office Js Excel Add in deployment
I have developed an excel add in using yeoman and i want to deploy the web application. Can I do it on linux server ? I am planning to update the web url in my manifest and share the manifest to other users. I get this error on linux. How can I disable sideloading.
I expect to deploy my excel add in on a web server (which is linux) and later distribute the  manifest file with updated web url.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can host the web app parts of the add-in on a Linux server if you want. Sharing copies of the manifest with end users is not a good way to deploy the add-in. Doing this would force each user to sideload the add-in every time they wanted to run it.

Without submitting to MSFT which I've heard isn't easy as a "regular user" or having a company w/ a MSFT Office 365, your best bet is likely hosting on a linux server and sharing the manifest as you've described. Just note, it's hard to update users manifests, they will need to re-sideload to update.
